# How to get NGINX to accept http://npomf/ as a proxy_pass?

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to setup [Npomf](https://github.com/maxpowa/nodepomf) on my vps and i run into this error when doing the setup instructions. I get an error at line 61 of [my config (hastebin)](https://h.mayo.pw/talitunidi.nginx). I cannot seem to resolve this `proxy_pass` issue, yet everything else works fine. Also, i am using NGINX **1.14.0**.